# Gnuplot Maximum Concurrent Lines within single Graph

Tags: real-time, pipe, gnuplot

I'm implementing real-time plotting with gnuPlot by sending the `plot '-'` command through pipe. I observed that the maximum number of lines that I can create on a single graph stops at 64. Is this limitation known to anyone? With the piped command I would push `plot '-' ... , '-' ... , '-' ....` and then the data in consecutive lines ending with `e\n`. I don't believe the issue lies in pipe as, if the buffer overflows it would simply flush first, and gnuPlot would wait until all the commands have arrived due to the `,` placed after each none terminating intermediate `'-'` command. Please provide insights if you know the solution. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't checked about this limit, but why do you need so many lines? I guess you cannot distinguish them properly (do you have 64 legend entries, 64 line types?) Maybe some other plotting style or stuff like `linecolor variable` would help.

Comment: @Christoph I'm basically displaying the FFT spectrum in time domain, and depending on the parameters, I could have many frequencies based on the resolution. I'm using `splot` for this one. Further Edit: I moved the legend down to the bottom and the lines are distinguishable.